# Changing the position of the Chapter heading

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

I am trying to alter the chapter heading that is preset in the book template. I have found a style I like from Vincent Zoonekynd’s web-page, http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html, however it has a large gap above the chapter heading and I cannot work out how to reduce this. My code is,

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}   

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{5\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ 
{\raggedleft \reset@font
  \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{10\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
{\raggedright \Huge \bfseries #1}%
\par\nobreak
\hrulefill
\par\nobreak
\vskip 20\p@
 }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{10\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ 
{\raggedleft \reset@font
  \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}\par\nobreak}%
\par\nobreak
\vspace*{30\p@}
\interlinepenalty\@M
{\raggedright \Huge \bfseries #1}%
\par\nobreak
\hrulefill
\par\nobreak
\vskip 10\p@
 }}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me reduce the white space above this?

Using the show frame package this is what my document looks like

[image]

Comment: The vertical spaces are introduced with `\vspace`. Please load package `showframe` to see what all this white space actually is.

Comment: I guess ideally I would like the 'Chapter 1' to be written in the first box and then the 'Introduction' to be higher up..

Comment: But the firs box is dedicated to pages header, not for any part of text. If you like to enlarge text height, than you need to change page layout in which you eliminate place for heading (by setting their height and after skip to zero).

Comment: is there anyway to at least remove the space above Chapter 1? And perhaps reduce the space between Introduction and the subheading? I have tried altering the above code, but cannot work out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple code with `titlesec`. You can play with `\titlespacing`: the first argument increases the left margin, the second is vertical space before the heading, and the third, vertical space after the heading.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\filleft\scshape\chaptername\enspace\thechapter}{-2pt}{\filright \Huge \bfseries}[\vskip4.5pt\titlerule]
 \titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{}{}{0pt}{\filright \Huge \bfseries}[\vskip4.5pt\titlerule]

 \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-15pt}{25.5pt}
 \titlespacing{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{16pt}{15pt}

 \begin{document}

 \chapter*{Introduction}

 \section{Intended Application of Particles}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The vertical spacing is controlled using `\vspace*`. You can set th value to your needs, negative values are also allowed, moving the text up on the page. A negative space of 105pt gives you the following output, though i cannot recommend to do that.

[image: erwChapterTitle]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}   
\usepackage{showframe,blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height ex \hfill
\kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-105\p@}%<-------------
    {\parindent \z@ 
        {\raggedleft \reset@font
            \scshape \@chapapp{}
        \thechapter\par\nobreak}%
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        {\raggedright \Huge \bfseries #1}%
        \par\nobreak
        \hrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    }}
        \begin{document}
        \chapter{Beloved Banana}
        \blindtext
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}` would be shorter ;-)

Comment: Might be, or not ;-)